# JBoss AS 6 Maven repository

Tags: maven-2, jboss6.x

I am upgrading an system I have been developing for some time now to JBoss AS 6 (6.0.0-Final). Everything works well with JBoss but I can't find a maven repository. I read the information on their web-site which directs me to: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases

However it only contains Jboss 4.2.3.GA?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that my question is incorrect. This is what I believe is the correct answer:
Maven2 always uses http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ as a fallback when packages are not found in the repositories supplied. So one should supply the jboss repository, https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/, but it will only contain jboss specific packages. For everything else (javaee packages and so on) the maven2 fallback reposity should be used.

I didn't understand that a Maven2 repository was always used as a fallback. So I got confused when I couldn't find the packages I needed in the Jboss repository.

Answer (score 0):

The groupId has changed to `org.jboss.as`

Here are [some 7.x Alpha releases](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/jboss/as/jboss-as-server/)

And here are some [6.x release links through nexus](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html#nexus-search;gav~org.jboss.jbossas~jboss-as-server~~~~kw,versionexpand) (couldn't find a browsable version of these)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I have been browsing jboss/nexus, https://repository.jboss.org/nexus, but I dosen´t help me much. For example Jboss6/EE6 uses JPA 2.0 but I can't find a package for it? I can neither find any JBoss6.0.0-Final package. So how are you supposed to use the new JBoss-maven2-nexus setup?